# How to implement listview using Usercontrol and a flowlayout panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to place Usercontrols on a flowlayout panel that act as a listview in C# (windows forms) . How can I implement selecting items here ?
Click event is not working when the user clicks on the controls of Usercontrol..
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.Click += new EventHandler(Clicked);
        }

        private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //click event code goes here
        }
```

Comment: let me try it..I want to change the backcolor when the usercontrol is clicked, which tells user that it is selected...